# Azure web app deployment output eating up bitbucket pipelines minutes

Tags: git, bitbucket, continuous-deployment, azure-web-app-service, bitbucket-pipelines

I have the following CI/CD setup:

push code to "origin/develop" branch => bitbucket pipelines runs integration tests and builds source => push to azure web app => azure web app installs node modules and starts

The problem is when pipelines pushes the built code to azure, the remote (i.e. the azure web app) sends output from the deployment back to the pipeline. This looks as follows:

```
+ git push --force https://$AZURE_LOGIN:$AZURE_PASSWORD@hostname.scm.azurewebsites.net/hostname.git build
remote: Updating branch 'build'.        
remote: ...............        
remote: Updating submodules.        
remote: Preparing deployment for commit id '...'.        
remote: Generating deployment script.        
remote: Running deployment command...
remote: Handling node.js deployment.        
remote: Kudu sync from: '/home/site/repository' to: '/home/site/wwwroot'
remote: ...........        
remote: Processed 706 files...        
remote: Detecting node version spec...        
remote: Using appsetting WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION value: 8.11        
remote: Node.js versions available on the platform are: 4.4.7, 4.5.0, 6.2.2, 6.6.0, 6.9.3, 6.10.3, 6.11.0, 8.0.0, 8.1.0, 8.2.1, 8.8.1, 8.9.4, 8.11.2, 9.4.0, 10.1.0.        
remote: Resolved to version 8.11.2        
remote: Detecting npm version spec...        
remote: Using default for node 8.11.2: 5.6.0        
remote: NPM versions available on the platform are: 2.15.8, 2.15.9, 3.9.5, 3.10.3, 3.10.10, 5.0.3, 5.4.2, 5.6.0, 6.0.1.        
remote: Resolved to version 5.6.0        
remote: Running "/opt/nodejs/8.11.2/bin/node" "/opt/npm/5.6.0/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js" install --production
```

The problem is that this last step is taking up quite a bit of time (around 8 minutes) which is unnecessarily eating up my pipelines minutes...

Is there a way to ignore the remote output from git in my bitbucket pipeline?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried adding an `&` after the command to detach it?

Comment: I tried this and while the output was suppressed, it also seemed to break the git push...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to build project , the remote output could not be ignored.

And if you don't want to build project, just want to deploy your project to `azure`,you could use **Deployment Center** .[image] Then you could choose **Bitbucket** or other tools to Synchronize code. After setting your Team,Repository,Branch, choose Sync to deploy. This way won't cost much time.

If you still have other questions, please let me know.

Comment: Ah yes, so simple! Actually this is very near to my current setup, but after building the code in pipelines, I was pushing it directly to the azure web application. Instead I should just push it to the bitbucket repository and let the azure webhook pick it up for deployment...

Thanks!